# bash script shuf and save in list

Tags: arrays, string, bash

I have A numbers and I want to chose B of them without repeting and save into a list.

Like this:

```
A="100"
B=5

a=$(gshuf -i 1-$B -n $A)
for i in ${a}
do
  echo $i
done
```

How Can I do it?

A is a string in my code and I am using gshuf instead of shuf because I am in a mac

Answer (score 1):

You may use `process substitution`:

```
A="100"
B=5

while read -r i; do
   echo "$i"
done < <(gshuf -i 1-$B -n $A)
```

If you want to save generated numbers in array then use:

```
arr=()
while read -r i; do
   arr+=("$i")
done < <(gshuf -i 1-$B -n $A)
```

Check content:

```
declare -p arr
```

Comment: But I need to save it into a variable a to use next